# How can I format a dictionary (originally from a dataframe) for operational use?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My current process is to use a loop to populate two lists, which are then converted into a dataframe, which is then converted into a dictionary which is to be used in a larger dataframe.

```
newdictionarydf = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': a_list, 'Col2': b_list})
mydictionary = newdictionarydf.to_dict(orient='dict')
```

The output is:

```
{'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'},
 'Col2': {0: 118, 1: 120, 2: 104}}
```

However, I am now trying to use this to build a new column in an existing dataframe using the map function, but receiving NaN values in the new column. I have ensured that the columns I am mapping from have the same name (Col1) incase that helped, but no luck.

```
bigdf['Col3'] = bigdf['Col1'].map(mydictionary)
# Output
   Col1 Col3
0  A    NaN
1  B    NaN
2  C    NaN
```

The output I would like is:

```
# Output
   Col1 Col3
0  A    118
1  B    120
2  C    104
```

I'm sure it's likely a simple error I'm making. I've also tried setting Col1 as the index between creating the dataframe and converting it to a dictionary but this didn't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
mydictionary = newdictionarydf.set_index("Col1")["Col2"].to_dict()
```

This will create:

```py
{'A': 118, 'B': 120, 'C': 104}
```

Then:

```
bigdf['Col3'] = bigdf['Col1'].map(mydictionary)
```

Creates:

```
  Col1  Col3
0    A   118
1    B   120
2    C   104
```

Comment: Great! Will mark this as the answer as soon as I can. Norie's response nulls the question, while this solves the question - Thank you.

Comment: you can map a series directly though: `.map(newdictionarydf.set_index("Col1")["Col2"])`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are converting the lists to a dataframe then the dataframe to a dictionary, you could use something like this to create the dictionary.

```
mydictionary = dict(zip(a_list, b_list))
```

If you then use that in the rest of the code you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Ah! That's a much better way to do it - Thank you.